# How to search for uppercase and lowercase html entities?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have utf8 characters saved as html entities in my database and I'm having trouble search on them.

Here's an example, we search for: Öregapám

```
in database it looks like this: &#214;Regap&#225;m
```

The problem: The user search for "öregapám", and he gets no results, but if the user search for "Öregapám", then he gets result.

```
$searchable = sql_escape($conn, $_GET['s']);
$search = convert($searchable);
```

The convert function converts utf8 characters to entities, like this:

```
$text = str_replace("Ö","&#214;",$text);
$text = str_replace("ö","&#246;",$text);
$text = str_replace("Á","&#193;",$text);
$text = str_replace("á","&#225;",$text);
...
```

Now the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted=0 and name LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY name ASC";
```

You can see the problem now.

```
Öregapám --> &#214;Regap'&#225;m (this matches)

öregapám --> &#246;Regap'&#225;m (this doesn't)
```

How can I make it, that when a user types in an utf8 character, it search for both the uppercase and lowercase character too?

I've tried this:

```
$search2 = mb_strtolower(html_entity_decode($searchable ,ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML401,'UTF-8'),'UTF-8' );
$search3 = mb_strtoupper(html_entity_decode($searchable ,ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML401,'UTF-8'),'UTF-8' );
$search2 = convert($search2);
$search3 = convert($search3);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted=0 and
(name LIKE '%".$search2."%' OR name LIKE '%".$search3 ."%') ORDER BY name ASC";
```

But this isn't working either, because it converts everything to lowercase or everything to uppercase, o typing in "Öregapám" doesn't even give a result,

```
because it search for "öregapám" (&#246;Regap&#225;m)
and "ÖREGAPÁM" (&#214;REGAP&#193;M)
instead of &#214;Regap&#225;m.
```

Comment: The `AND` between the `LIKE` expressions in your query should be an `OR`. Also you have `'%".$search."%'` which should be `'%".$search2."%'`

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted=0 and name LIKE '%".$search."%' OR name LIKE '%".$search3 ."%' ORDER BY name ASC";` you were checking for both uppercase and lowercase instead you should look only for uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: This still doesn't solve my issue, the issue is still the same as said in the last 3 lines above.